# What does "IntegrityError. NOT NULL constraint failed: blog_comment.post_id " stands for?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I've added a Comment model to my application, but when the form is submitted, this error pops:

NOT NULL constraint failed: blog_comment.post_id

Here's models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_pics/', null=True, blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    text = models.TextField(null=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

This is the part for creating a comment in views.py:

```
class AddCommentView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['text']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

My forms.py:

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['text']
```

The html form:

```
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">New Comment</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Publish</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: `post` is foreign key column and it's required in db level. You must set value for it. It can't null

Comment: Thanks, the comment is being added now, but not shown on the post detail view. When I go to the admin panel, to the comments, I can see the added comments, but thei are not being assigned to the post. If I select the post from the drop down, the comment is shown. Where could I be getting wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You must set the value for `post` because it's a foreign key. In `form_valid` you should define `post = Post.objects.get(id=current_post_id)` and you can get `current_post_id` from the url or receive it as a parameter. Then assign it: `form.instance.post = post`

Comment: I didn't understand you - how can I define post and get the current post id?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is you need to pass the id of the post in the url or as a form field, otherwise django can't retrieve the post.id when you create the comment.

In your url add
`path('post/<pk>/add-comment', AddCommentView.as_view(), name='add_comment'),`

Your view in form_valid

`def form_valid(self, form):
        comment=form.save(commit=False)
        comment.post=self.kwargs.get(pk)
        comment.save()
        super().form_valid(form)`

Inside the template in the form tag add `action = "{% url 'add_comment' post.pk%}"`

Of course this need to be passed inside a template thatdisplay a post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your `forms.py`:

```python
from django.forms import ModelForm, widgets

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['post', 'text']
        widgets = {
            'post': widgets.HiddenInput
        }
```

If u will have problems with a redirect, change your `def get_absolute_url in comment-model` to:

```python
 def get_absolute_url(self):
     self.article_url = Article.objects.get(id=self.article_id).get_absolute_url()
     return self.article_url
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to set post_id for your comment.** I've just solved this problem myself. I'll try to explain everything as detailed as possible.

First, go to your `urls.py` and make sure you have a valid path for your `AddCommentView`. It should look similar to this:

```
path('post/<int:pk>/addcomment/', AddCommentView.as_view(), name='comment-create'),
```

The `pk` argument is the primary key for Post object, which you are trying to comment. Also do not forget to import AddCommentView from your views.

Second, go to your `views.py` and correct `form_valid` function in `AddCommentView` class:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs['pk']
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Your whole class should looke like this:

```
class AddCommentView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['text']  # filds to be displayed in your form. You may also use your custom form_class
    template_name = 'blog/comment_form.html'  # html template with your form

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs['pk']  # this is line sets post_id with pk from url
        form.instance.author = self.request.user  # in case you need to display author
        return super().form_valid(form)

    # returns url where you 'll be redirected after the form is correctly filled
    def get_success_url(self):
        pk = self.kwargs["pk"]
        return reverse("post-detail", kwargs={"pk": pk})
```

Finally, go to your html template, where you have your "add comment" button. In your case, it should be called `post_detail.html`. Make sure that you pass `pk` and url name (aka `comment-create`) correctly. Add this code:

```
<a class="text-muted" href="{% url 'comment-create' object.pk %}"> Add comment</a>
```

P.S.
Found solution in this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OuOB9ADT_bo&list=PLCC34OHNcOtr025c1kHSPrnP18YPB-NFi&index=36)

P.P.S
This is my very first answer on stackoverflow. Hope it helped someone.